# Word 2003 Template - document saving

Tags: templates, ms-word, save

We have a word 2003 template we use as the basis for a configuration sheet for a system.  The whole thing is based around form fields and the template is then locked.  To write a new document we double click on the template, fill in the form fields, save and off we go.
The problem Ive got is that when finished writing in the "doc" file and closing or saving I always get a dialog asking if I want to save changes to the template as well.  Even if I just double click the template "dot" file so that a blank "doc" file based on this is opened and then close that document straightaway I still get the save template query.
Is there anyway I can get rid of it as its damned annoying to everyone who uses the template.

Many thanks

**Further note:**

I've just had Word 2003 opened with no documents or templates opened. I use file open and open the template.  Once it is open I then close it again.  No "do you want to save" messages.  I then use windows explorer and double click on the same template to create a document.  I wait til the document is sitting in word ready to use.  I then click close again without typing or changing anything - After the do you want to save changes to "Document 2" which I say no to, I then get the "do you want to save the template" message.

**Further further note:**

I have now tracked this to some code I have that adds a toolbar and buttons. within this code is a line `customizationcontext = Thisdocument` and then the toolbar and buttons are created.  If I change the line to `CustomizationContext = ActiveDocument` I then do not get the prompt for saving when I close a document created from the template.  I do however now get the prompt if I open the template and close it without changing anything(also the buttons I added do not appear correctly (but they do appear in the document))!  I can live with this though as it is preferable than the other way round.

Comment: It is unclear from your post if the "save changes to template" message was there from the initial creation of the template or if the message appeared after some use. If the template previously created document copies without a "template save" message, a user probably altered the template by inadvertently editing it (right-click|Open is the usual culprit). To correct it, just copy a working backup over it and you should be good to go. If the behavior was there since the template's creation, seeing the template's code would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason for this to happen, is that one of your formats (paragraph or other) is marked to update the source template if changed.

Check all the used formats in your template if the option to save back changes is activated and de-activate this option - the same applies to any .doc already created from this template since it will carry over this option.

To check your formats (in Word 2003), open the sidebar for styles and formatting, change the filter at the bottom to "Used formats". Move your pointer over the format you like to inspect and select the action "Modify..." from the pull down menu at the right.

On the bottom right - just above the OK-button - you'll find the checkbox labeled "Automatically update".

See also [Automatically update a paragraph style](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/automatically-update-a-paragraph-style-HP005189552.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  can you tell me how I can check to see if this 'update source template/save back changes' option is switched on?  Thanks

Comment: @Keith I updated my answer with a how-to and a reference to MS.